# How do I document a string double array in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I can't seem to find an example for this. But I have a string double array (table cell data), and I want to document it in my JSDoc.

Compiler doesn't seem to like this:

```
/**    
 * @param {cells: [[String]]} tableData
 */
```

And it doesn't have anything particularly nice to say about this:

```
/**    
 * @param {cells: String[][]} tableData
 */
```

Answer (score 4):

how about this:

```
 /**    
  * @param  {Object<Array<String>>}  tableData
  */
```

reference: http://wiki.servoy.com/display/public/DOCS/Annotating+JavaScript+using+JSDoc#AnnotatingJavaScriptusingJSDoc-TypeExpression

Comment: yeah seems right. i gotta check next week. too busy with other stuff right now